# R: How to get random forest values scaled continuously?

Tags: r

I am trying to run a random forest on my dataset. Sample code is below then I will explain the issue I am running into!

```r
library(randomForest)
Pitches <- data.frame("Linear_weight" = c("1.39", "1.01", "-0.04", 
                     "-0.21", "-0.11", "-0.33"),
                     "Vel" = c("93.5", "95.0", "97.1", "90.0", "80.1", 
                     "100.3"),
                     "HorzBrk" = c("5.0", "8.1", "10.0", "9.1", "3.0", 
                     "6.0"))

sample <- sample(1:nrow(Pitches),0.5*nrow(Pitches)) 

#generate training data
training <- Pitches[sample,]

#generate testing data
testing <- Pitches[-sample,]

set.seed(1234)

RFM = randomForest(as.factor(Linear_weight) ~ Vel + HorzBrk, data = 
Pitches)

Weight_pred = predict(RFM, training)
testing$Weight_pred = Weight_pred
```

So, the model is working how I've coded it to. However, I want the randomForest to make a "continuous" prediction. Right now it is predicting the outcomes, but only based on the available linear weights. For example, if a value is between 1.39 and 1.01 I want a number between the two, not rounded up or down to 1.39 or 1.01 like it is doing now. So, I am basically just in search of a more accurate prediction.

My dataset is very large, I just used the above as an example. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you possibly looking for predicting the probabilities (between 0 and 1) instead of predicting the class?

Answer (score 0):

I recast in tidymodels, as the model specification `randomForest_spec` lets you be very clear about the type of modelling you are doing. I took your goal as being predicting values, but if you want to do classification, then the mode becomes 'classification'. In the Pitches data frame definition, I removed the quotes, as these where making what looks like continuous variables into characters. In the formula, I removed the `as.factor`, so that the prediction could be continuous.

```
library(tidymodels)

Pitches <- data.frame("Linear_weight" = c(1.39, 1.01, -0.04, 
                                          -0.21, -0.11, -0.33),
                      "Vel" = c(93.5, 95.0, 97.1, 90.0, 80.1, 
                                100.3),
                      "HorzBrk" = c(5.0, 8.1, 10.0, 9.1, 3.0, 
                                    6.0))

set.seed(502)
pitches_split <- initial_split(Pitches, prop = 0.80)
pitches_train <- training(pitches_split)
pitches_test  <- testing(pitches_split)

pitches_rec <- 
  recipe(Linear_weight ~ Vel + HorzBrk, data = pitches_train)

randomForest_spec <-
  rand_forest() |>
  set_engine('randomForest') |>
  set_mode('regression')

pitches_wflow <- 
  workflow() |> 
  add_model(randomForest_spec) |> 
  add_recipe(pitches_rec)

pitches_fit <- fit(pitches_wflow, pitches_train)

predict(pitches_fit, pitches_test)
```

`mtry` and `min_n` should be tuned, and the data frame is small, so you'll get a warning on this toy data set.

Hope this helps! :-)